# Varnish: Is it possible to log all GET requests for further processing?

Tags: varnish

Is it possible to use Varnish for the following task?

Imagine an URL(e.g. /vote?poll-id=1&answer-id=2) that is requested via direct links where we display poll results for the chosen poll-id.

I would like to save/pull/process all those requested URL(in near real time) to generate those poll results.

Is it possible to get those URLs as some sort of stream for further processing?

The reason why Varnish is used is because I would like to reduce the load on a slower upstream backend service. And because some delay in showing the actual results is OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Varnish has built-in [shared memory logs](http://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.5/reference/vsl.html). These can be consulted using various tools.

The main ones that could be useful for you are:

- varnishlog: in-depth logging about every aspect of the request, response, and internal processing
- varnishncsa: an Apache/NCSA style logging tool

You can also leverage the *VCL* programming language and log requests from within *VCL* to the operating system's `syslog` mechanism.

### varnishlog

The following command will display all logging information for URLs that start with `/vote`:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl ~ '^/vote'"
```

You can filter out the fields you need:

```
varnishlog -i requrl -i reqheader -g request -q "ReqUrl ~ '^/vote'"
```

This one will only display the request URL and all request headers.

You can also write the output to a file:

```
varnishlog -A -a -w /var/log/varnish/vsl_vote.log -i requrl -i reqheader -g request -q "ReqUrl ~ '^/vote'"
```

See http://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.5/reference/varnishlog.html to learn more about `varnishlog` and http://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.5/reference/vsl-query.html to learn more about the `vsl-query` language.

### varnishncsa

If you want Apache-style logging, you can use the following command:

```
varnishncsa -g request -q "ReqUrl ~ '^/vote'"
```

You can also write these logs to a logfile:

```
varnishncsa -a -w /var/log/varnish/vote_access.log -g request -q "ReqUrl ~ '^/vote'"
```

> Both `varnishncsa` and `varnishlog` binaries can be daemonized using the `-D` parameter

See http://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.5/reference/varnishncsa.html to learn more about `varnishncsa`. There is also a section in the docs about including custom fields into your `varnishncsa` output.

### syslog from *VCL*

If you use the following snippet, you can log vote requests to `syslog`:

```
vcl 4.1;
import std;

sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.url ~ "^/vote") {
        std.syslog(6, "Vote request captured: " + req.url);
    } 
}
```

> This is boilerplate *VCL* that cannot just be copy/pasted like that. Please make sure to add `import std;` to your *VCL file*, and use `std.syslog()` to log to your local syslog facility.

See http://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.5/reference/vmod_std.html#void-syslog-int-priority-string-s to learn more about `std.syslog()`.